# Can we pass string values to the contract which holds bytes 32 only in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

My contract can hold only array of type bytes32 only. How can we store string values as well?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your strings into a bytes32 types and use those. Remember that bytes32 has a limited length so your string can only be of limited length.

You gave your example contract in the comments and here's a fixed version of it (mostly added missing `memory` declaration):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Student { 
    bytes32[32] parameters; 
    function setParameters(bytes32[] memory _parameters) public { 
        for (uint i = 0; i < _parameters.length; i++) { 
            parameters[i] = _parameters[i];
        } 
    }
}
```

If you input that into a fresh Remix you can call the function with for example parameters: `["0x63616e6469646174653100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x6332000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x6333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]` - that data is rubbish and just found it online somewhere but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is my contract. It takes only Bytes32 as parameters. How can I give string as parameters.

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Student {
 bytes32[32] parameters;
function setParameters(bytes32[] _parameters) public {
for (uint i = 0; i < _parameters.length; i++) {
 parameters[i] = _parameters[i];
      }
      
}}

Comment: You can't give it string as parameter. You have to convert them before sending to the contract.

Comment: After converting the string to bytes32 how can I call that that. Can I have the example please. Thank you.

Comment: edited answer to hopefully answer your more detailed questions

Comment: Thanks for the response. After writing the stringtobytes32 function how can i call that function in my above contract to call string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `yourStrings` is your input array of strings...

If you're on web3 v0.x:

```
const params = yourStrings.map(x => web3.fromAscii(x).padEnd(66, "0"));
```

If you're on web3 v1.x:

```
const params = yourStrings.map(x => web3.utils.asciiToHex(x).padEnd(66, "0"));
```

Then pass `params` to your contract's function.

Of course, every string in `yourStrings` must be no be longer than 32 characters.